# Virtual Directory using Command Line

Tags: windows, iis-7, batch-file

How to create a new virtual directory in IIS 7 on Windows 2008 using command line. 
Can you please provide me a command. So that i can add that command in my batch script.

Assume name of VDIR i want to create is ZFP and it has to be created under Default Web Site.

Answer (score 6):

From Microsoft's Technet [Create a Virtual Directory (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771804%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

> appcmd add vdir /app.name:string/ /path:string /physicalPath:string

See also [Start Appcmd.exe (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730918%28v=ws.10%29.aspx): The appcmd executable is not on the default system path and this article explains its location.

Answer (score 0):

I always use `SUBST` to create virtual folders in Windows, but I am not sure if it will work in IIS. Try the following:

```
SUBST  K:   C:\MYFOLDER
```

In the above example, a new virtual drive (with letter `K:`) will be created and its contents will be whatever inside (`C:\MYFOLDER`)

Comment: i am automating installation of an application. If we install that application manually it creates a vitrual dir automatically. But when i am runining msi of that application through a script, the installation rollbacks after a certain point that is when need to create virtual directory. So i want to automate the creation of virtual directory.

Comment: virtual directory in IIS is not the same as virtual directory in Windows filesystem